# Show Last Clicked Elements in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have BorderPane with a lot of different figures, triangles, hexagons, circles, groups with images and a figure. Then I have a dialog which asks to click first a triangle and then a circle. What is the best way to get the last two clicked elements in that BorderPane?

I know I can use MouseEvent for a single object to see if it's clicked or not, like this:

```
hexagon.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            System.out.println("hexagon clicked");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set ID for BorderPane(suppose `root`) and each of the elements(suppose for Rectangle `rectangle1`, `rectangle2`). Then can check if it's elements were pressed or not. Here is a sample code:

```
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            if (hexagon.isPressed())
                System.out.println("hexagon");
            else if (rectangle1.isPressed())
                System.out.println("rectangle1");
            else if (rectangle2.isPressed())
                System.out.println("rectangle2");
            else if (imageView1.isPressed())
                System.out.println("imageView1");
            else if (imageView2.isPressed())
                System.out.println("imageView2");
            else
                System.out.println("Others");

        }
    });
```